# Getting frameless windows to open only in current activity

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fedora, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

Some applications, such as Chrome and Firefox, have their own draggable titlebar and look much nicer without the system border.

[image: FF&Chrome with plasma borders] [image: FF&Chrome naked]

However, this appears to come at a cost. Irrespective of whether you enable this feature through the application or using plasma's own (KWin) settings, the next window you open will be present on all activities.

[image: Chrome's native title bar remover]
[image: KWin must be used for firefox]

Disabling this, and going back to using system borders, has new program instances obey activities again.

I noticed that there is a setting to choose which activity the program opens to, but the only options are "All Activities" and a list of activities [to always open to] (no "Current Activity" option, that must be the  default, unchecked, setting..which isn't working).

[image]

Is there a way to get it to behave?
Maybe a keyboard shortcut that traps the current window to the current activity (just as there are shortcuts to move the window to another desktop)?
Or possibly aliasing the executables with a small script that calls the program, but puts it into the activity manually using dbus or something?

Comment: This might be related: [Windows with no border (decoration) are visible on all activities](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274931)

Comment: `X11 will not see any more features`, `Wayland lacks Activity support in general`, well that's fun. I'm still thinking there has to be `a keyboard shortcut that traps the current window to the current activity` or something, given you can change the activity through the Alt+F3 menu. Even if it's a shortcut to a script that gets the current window ID and uses `dbus` to force an activity (I dont know enough about `dbus` to write this myself though)

Comment: Let me know if you figure out a way to do it :-)

Comment: @EECOLOR it was pretty simple, 'just needed to think outside the box trying to fix  the border issue instead of the activity issue

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I have a valid work around. Instead of a shortcut to set the current activity (which appears impossible without scripting), why not let plasma handle that as it does when it adds a border, and have a shortcut to remove the border?

1. **In the app (chrome in this case) prepare it to show without borders as usual;**
   *`right click area next to tabs` → uncheck `Use system title bar and borders`*
   [image]
   This gets chrome to make it's own close, minimise, maximise buttons.
2. **Tell plasma to ignore this setting;**
   *`Alt-F3` in the app <sup>(or click its icon in the top-left before step 1)</sup> → `More Actions` → `Special Window Settings` → `Appearance & Fixes` → `No titlebar and frame` → `Apply Initially` → `No` → `Okay`*
   [image][image]
   This makes plasma lock new windows to the current activity.
3. **Add a shortcut to remove the border manually;**
   *`System Settings` → `Shortcuts` → `Global Shortcuts` → `KWin` → `Hide Window Border` → `Custom` <sup>(I used 
   <kbd>❖</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>)</sup>*
   [image]

Now whenever I open a chrome window I just have to hit <kbd>❖</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and the borders disappear, and it stays on the activity I opened it on.